# Python equivalent of Perl $+ aka $LAST_PAREN_MATCH

Tags: python, perl, regex-group

(Apologies if this is a duplicate, but it is impossible to google/search `$+`!)

I'm looking for the nearest/best equivalent to Perl's `$+` aka `$LAST_PAREN_MATCH`.

For those who don't know Perl it is described like this:

```
$LAST_PAREN_MATCH
$+      The text matched by the last bracket of the last successful search
        pattern. This is useful if you don't know which one of a set of
        alternative patterns matched.
```

That is if I have a pattern like `(b)|(a)|(r)` then `$+` will contain either `b`, `a` or `r` depending on which subpattern matched.

The best that I have is

```
next((g for g in reversed(match.groups(None)) if g is not None),None)[0]
```

Which seems like a lot of code for a simple thing to a longtime Perl hacker.
(Not that I'm unaware that I could wrap it in a function `last_paren_match(match)` :-)

Answer (score 7):

There may be no equivalent in Python, but if you use the *branch reset* pattern `(?|...)` then each alternation pipe `|` in the pattern will reset the counter for the capture variables. I'm pretty sure that will be supported in Python

In this example, all capture groups are saved in `$1`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

'zax' =~ /(?|(b)|(a)|(r))/;

say $1;
```

#### output

```
a
```

Comment: A quick documentation grep shows that `(?|...)` is supported by the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) but not by the [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). I'll give you an upvote since I should have thought of this! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MatchObject's [`lastindex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.lastindex) attribute:

> The integer index of the last matched capturing group, or `None` if no group was matched at all. For example, the expressions `(a)b`, `((a)(b))`, and `((ab))` will have `lastindex == 1` if applied to the string `'ab'`, while the expression `(a)(b)` will have `lastindex == 2`, if applied to the same string.

For example:

```py
>>> import re
>>> m = re.match(r'(b)|(a)|(r)', 'abc')
>>> m.group(m.lastindex)
'a'
```

Note that this is different from Perl's `$+` when you have nested capturing groups:

```
$ python -c'import re; m = re.match(r"((a)(b))", "ab"); print m.group(m.lastindex)'
ab
$ perl -E'"ab" =~ /((a)(b))/; say $+'
b
```

---

Personally, I would just capture the entire alternation instead of capturing each alternative separately:

```
>>> m = re.match(r'(b|a|r)', 'abc')
>>> m.group(1)
'a'
```

Comment: capturing the entire alternation into group 1 doesn't work if any of the alternatives may contain uncaptured substrings, e.g. `s/\\(.)|(")/\\$+/g` to escape quotes in a string but leaving already escaped characters alone is trivial in Perl.

Comment: Granted `re.sub(r'(\\.)|"',(lambda m: m.group(1) or r'\"'), ...)` will do the trick but it is a lot more to type. And note that negative lookbehind for a backslash won't work if the quote is preceded by an even number of backslashes!

Comment: To only escape quotes preceded by an even number of backslashes, use `((?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*")`, e.g. `re.sub(r'((?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*")', r'\\\1', r'\\"')`. This is also much more efficient than `\\(.)|(")`.

Comment: Yes that does indeed do the trick. Thanks. I'll update my question to actually include the quote escaping example and if you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @bpj That actually changes the question pretty significantly, so I rolled back your edit. It's best not to change questions after you've gotten answers. Feel free to post a new question about your actual use-case if it's not a duplicate of an existing question, and in the future, beware of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).